# Transparent status bar and constraint to its bottom

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-statusbar

I want to get transparent status bar. I managed to get it with this code:

```
   WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window,false)
   WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window,window.decorView).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = false
```

This is the result:
[image]

But now my view (dagger) constrained to the top of the parent layout, also get to the status bar place, I don't need it.

I want to constraint it to the bottom of the status bar. I can use a margin, but it's not a good solution.

I tried to use fitSystemWindow for container, but it did't work

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the status bar's insets to avoid it, you can update the top margin for your view (let's say it's toolbar) using the inset:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(toolbar) { view, windowInsets ->
     val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
     view.updateLayoutParams<MarginLayoutParams> {
         topMargin = insets.top
     }
     WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
}
```

Read more about how to [Handle overlaps using insets](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge#handle-overlaps) when implementing edge-to-edge.